# Swift accessing nested array element specified by `NSIndexPath`

Tags: swift, indexing

If I have nested arrays like this:

```
array[0].children[0].children[0].children[2]
```

How can I access one of the nested elements? I know the `NSIndexPath` type exists to represent an index path into nested arrays, but how can I access the element specified by a given `NSIndexPath`?

Comment: Are you just looking for a shorter implementation of array[0].children[0].children[0].children[2], like array(0.0.0.2) or something?

Comment: The problem not in implementation but in locating that arrays using short numeric syntax

Comment: You should just be able to call arrays[0][0][0][2], if I'm assuming your question correctly

Comment: arrays[0][0][0][2] is make an error! also i need something i can use if Array has 30 Array for example!!

Comment: NSIndexPath is god solution, but i did't understand how to use it .

Comment: This is indicative of a really bad design. Apart from certain exceptional situations, you shouldn't have 30 nested arrays.

Comment: @user2713544 I've edited the question to help others understand what you're asking. I hope I've interpreted you correctly.

Comment: I have a big tree for Book index, so i have many children to manage there data

Comment: Do you know how many levels the root array can have? I mean how many children? It's is variable or do you have a maximum?

Comment: I have many Books, some of them have 4 levels  and another have 10 levels, so i have to make a mechanism to take this levels automatically

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Finally I find the simplest way to locate nested array elements:

It's by use KeyPath to locate inside Arrays, like this:

```
class BookIndex: NSObject {
  var title = ""
  var children = [BookIndex]()
}
var root = BookIndex()
```

And i can set value inside "children" if i have 3 children like this:

```
root.setValue([BookIndex()], forKeyPath: "children.children.chlidren")
```

Or I can just locate to it like this:

```
root.valueforKeyPath("children.children.chlidren")
```

Because of "keyPath" is a String, you can generate the path inside the loop as you need with no limits!

Comment: This will not work because `BookIndex.children` is an array of `BookIndex`, so when you use the "string" as path key, you are not indicating *which* array index are you accessing.

Answer (score 0):

I would try a recursive function. However, since you don't know the levels in your tree, you could try something like searching for an specific path.

Let's assume your *node* class is something like this:

```
class Node<T> {
    var data: T
    var children: Array<Node<T>>?

    init(data: T, children: Array<Node<T>>?) {
        self.data = data
        self.children = children
    }
}
```

You can make a function like this:

```
func getNChildren<T>(head: Array<Node<T>>, path: Array<Int>) -> Node<T>? {
    var localPath = path
    // Get the first path and remove it from the array
    let currentPath = localPath.removeFirst()

    if head.indices.contains(currentPath) {
        if localPath.isEmpty {
            // If there's no more in the path, return current element
            return head[currentPath]
        } else {
            if head[currentPath].children != nil {
                // We go looking for children
                return getNChildren(head[currentPath].children!, path: localPath)
            } else {
                // There are no more children, but there are more elements in path, so that level doesn't exist
                return nil
            }
        }

    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

This function get the element at path if it exists, if not, returns nil (to avoid crashing when looking for non existing indices).

And you can call the function like this:

```
let elementAt = getNChildren(tree, path: [0, 0, 0, 2])

let elementAt = getNChildren(tree, path: [0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 2, 1, 3, 4, 0, 3])
```

I know this is not the best approach but maybe it can be useful.

> UPDATE:

To add data to the *Node* you have to make this:

```
let root = Node(data: 0, children: nil)
let child1 = Node(data: 1, children: nil)
let child2 = Node(data: 1, children: nil)
root.children = [child1, child2]
let arr = [root]
```

Of course you can use any data type as `data`, that's why the `Node` class is marked to be generic `<T>`.

And you can make a function to recursively insert children to the nodes if you feel more comfortable doing that.

Comment: @user2713544 I have updated my answer, please check again.

Comment: Excellent !! One more thing please: can i use anther func to edit the data same way: like: setNChildren(tree, path: [0,0,7]) = something

Comment: Of course! But you would have to pass the data as parameter: `setNChildren(tree, path: [0,0,7], data: something)`

Comment: I tried this: getNChildren(arr, path: [0,0,0], data: BookIndex()) where (BookIndex) is my data Class but i got this message: extra argument 'data' in call !

Comment: Yes, because you are calling the `get` function, not the new `set` one.

Comment: I tried : setNChildren(arr, path: [0,0,0], data: BookIndex()) and get error: use of unresolved identifier 'setNChildren' .... how to make setNChildren

Comment: And did you created that function? I believe this is another question (I believe I already answer this question, right?). If you agree with me please create another question I will be happy to help you with that too ;)

Comment: Thank you so much, i will try to build the function based on get function, and if i can't i will add another question .

Comment: I make another question for setting the data: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38535973/swift-setting-nested-array-element-specified-by-nsindexpath

Comment: Excuse me.. the answer work only for 2 level, when i make 3 or 4 level it get nil value

Comment: @user2713544 are you sure your tree has more than 2 levels?

Comment: It is like this: Earth ->Europe ->Italy ->Roma ->somewhere in Roma !

Comment: @user2713544 Can you show me how you are creating the tree?

Comment: I add a new question with exactly what i want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38537350/swift-store-data-in-complex-tree-array-to-use-it-in-nsoutlineview

Comment: @user2713544 OK so you are not creating the tree. How do you expect it to work for 4 levels if you don't even have a tree?

Comment: So this is my question: how to make a tree if iI don't have a way to deep inside "children" in the Node

Comment: I believe you don't understand how trees work, so I suggest you start by learning how trees work first.

Comment: I am sorry .. didn't saw your update .. thank you i thing this will help